# Endless slide show in horizontal direction

Tags: jquery, slideshow, infinite-scroll

A few days ago I found a very interesting slideshow on http://www.billboard.com/. I tried figuring out how rebuild it, but I miserably failed.

That's what I already accomplished, my knowledge of jQuery is not that good to complete it.

Here is a Dropbox-link for all of you, who want to get a little preview of my code for realizing my basic idea.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pb19ydkkr7du2cl/slide.php

So it's up to you guys, hopefully you can possibly give me an "easy" solution to my problem (endless slide and interval switch between its content).

Comment: Please, post the code, related to your problem: here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt look at your code, but from the top of my head, I'd say you need something like a bootstrap Carousel : http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

Its pretty easy to set up. All the docs are in that link I've added to this answer. Just to be basic, you'll keep the next and prev icons in an `<ol>`, and each image in a div with class `item` :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: pls feel free to mark this as the right answer if you think this has helped u :)